# Permission request window not closing when accepting after denying permission in Android?

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

When the app starts up, this code is run, requesting a permission.

```
public void requestPermission()
{
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[] {  android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION  },
            Integer.parseInt(this.getString(R.string.LOCATION_REQUESTCODE)));
}
```

The user can then accept or deny the permission. It then runs the following code.

```
  @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults)
    {
        if(requestCode == Integer.parseInt(this.getString(R.string.LOCATION_REQUESTCODE)))
        {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                // permission was granted
                // Continue running the application
            }
            else
            {
                // permission denied
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.gps_required, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Ask again to accept the permissions
                requestPermission();
            }
        }
    }
```

So if the request is denied, a toast shows the user needs to accept it in order to run the application (since the GPS coordinates are required) and the app requests the permissions again from the user.

**But the problem is:** when denying, the popup comes again. If I deny 5 times, then I want to accept, I need to click accept for 5 times before all the pop-ups dissapear.

Any idea what is causing this? Why are there still permission popups after accepting?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
        new String[] {  android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION  },
        Integer.parseInt(this.getString(R.string.LOCATION_REQUESTCODE)));
```

I'm requesting 2 permissions: `android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`so that's why the popup comes up twice.

The solution was to remove the `android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` because the `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` already includes that.